# How can I filter dataframe in pandas so that values are between a certain range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on an uber dataset with Pandas and I am encountering a problem. I am trying to use a gps route tool that takes in longitude and latitude and returns driving time. The issue is some of the values for longitude and latitude exceed the -90 to 90 range, and I was wondering how to clean up the data so it could be effectively used by the gps tool.

The distance function here:

```
def distance(df):
    
    dist = []
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        
        pickup = (row['pickup_latitude'], row['pickup_longitude'])
        dropoff = (row['dropoff_latitude'], row['dropoff_longitude'])
        dist_miles = geopy.distance.vincenty(pickup, dropoff).mi
        dist.append(dist_miles)
        
    return dist
```

Here is calling the distance function

```
df_n = uberdata.iloc[:, [4,5,6,7]] #Taking the long and lat of pickup and dropoff

distance_travelled = distance(df_n)

df_n['distance'] = pd.DataFrame({'distance':distance_travelled})
```

How could I call this so that it only takes the values from df_n that are in the range of -90 and 90?

Comment: kindly provide a sample dataframe with few rows (5 - 10), along with the expected output dataframe

Comment: You can just filter out the out-of-bound rows before calling the function. I have more questions about your choice of Vincenty distance though. (1) Most Uber trips are within a city-sized area (~50km radius). At that distance, the Earth can be treated as flat. If so there is a [vectorized method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) to calculate the Euclidean distance. (2) Uber don't drive through buildings so I think Manhanttan distance is more appropiate.